# Facebook Sdk is not initializing

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to enable the javascript facebook login on my site and I keep getting a javascript error saying FB is not defined.  I folowed the dev guide on facebook exactly and I do not believe the fbasyncinit is actually working.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

My initialization code is directly after my opening  in my layout page.

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function ()
        {
            FB.init(
            {
                appId            : 'xxxxxxxxx',
                autoLogAppEvents : true,
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v3.0'
            });

            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $(document.body).on('click', '#facebook-login', function ()
                {
                    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response)
                    {
                        alert(response);
                    });
                });
            });
        };

        (function (d, s, id)
        {
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

When I click on my #facebook-login button it hits the FB.getLoginStatus() but then always throws the "JavaScript runtime error: 'FB' is undefined".  I am debugging on my local machine, but I have tried pushing this code to my development machine that has an external IP, which I've changed my fbook developer app url to that url and it still doesn't work.

All google results I've found are from multiple years ago and have not helped at all.

** Update 1 **
I tried putting this ajax call in my document.ready and it always fails.  So maybe the problem is with the url for retrieving the SDK?  I tried the url with and without the "https:"

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success:function(script, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        FB.init(
        {
            appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v3.0'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
    },
    error:function(){ alert("Failed")}
});
```

Comment: It makes no sense to nest document.ready into fbAsyncInit this way. The latter will fire when the SDK script is finished loading asynchronously, but at that point the ready event likely has occurred already. And nesting document.ready into itself “recursively” doesn’t make sense either.

Comment: That wasn't helpful.  I have tried this many different ways.  This just happened to be the last one I tried.  The problem is that thefbAsyncInit isn't working right and the FB object never gets initialized.

Comment: Well just trial & error isn’t that much more helpful IMHO either. You got to approach stuff like this a little more methodical. _“So maybe the problem is with the url for retrieving the SDK?”_ - that’s something you can easily find out via your browser dev tools. _“I folowed the dev guide on facebook exactly”_ - well what you have shown here contained a lot of additional stuff. So try with the exact code first, before you add your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript SDK was being blocked by a proxy on my work's network.  I was able to login from my phone(which wasn't on the network).  But I figured it out by looking at the network traffic when I put the url for the sdk in a browser.